# setting correct WORKDIR in a multi-stage build for docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build, docker-multi-stage-build

I wish to build a docker image that can start a container where I can use both node version 14 and lz4. The dockerfile I have so far is:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update
RUN apk add --upgrade lz4
```

`node --version` and `lz4 --help` seem to run ok with the `docker run` command - but I wanted to ask whether there is a specific `WORKDIR` I should be using in the dockerfile to follow any best practices (if any exist), or does it not matter what I set the WORKDIR to? Note I'm not sure of all my future requirements, but I may need to use this image to build other images in the future, so I want to ensure `WORKDIR` is set appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WORKDIR` should be set to set the working directory for the subsequent docker commands in dockerfile, which makes things a little easy to understand as the paths will be relative to the working directory.

By default, `/` root dir is the set working directory. Without setting any other workdir, all the commands can have absolute paths which make it even more easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter much. Besides, you could always change it for your future builds.